# Functions that generate "easy" matrices of full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education

While explaining how to invert matrices I once used this ill-fated example 
$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\4&5&6 \\7&8&9 \end{pmatrix}$ which can not be inverted ($\det(A)=0$). That got me thinking, given a matrix of size $N$, what are some good functions that map to the elements such that:

1. The elements are integers
2. The elements are "small" (for hand calculation)
3. The matrix is always invertible
4. (optional) the function has a random component, but still satisfies (3)

Let $A_{ij} = f(j + (i-1)N)$. In the example above $f(n) = n$.

Comment: A random matrix is invertible with high probability, so just choose the entries randomly. Alternately, choose an upper-triangular matrix with nonzero diagonal entries. These are a little easier to invert than a general matrix but you'll still learn something from actually doing it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan while that may be true, I want to be 100% _positive_  that the rows are linearly independent. I guess I'm also interested in the problem itself, what functions generate matrices in $GL(\mathbb{Z},N)$ (did I say that correctly)?

Comment: The matrix with entries $a_{j,k}=\min(j,k)$ is symmetric and invertible. If you really want a guaranteed nonsingular matrix with integer entries, then multiply a lower triangular matrix and an upper triangular matrix, both having nonzero diagonal entries (as Qiaochu alludes to).

Comment: Have a look at the [Pascal matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) as well.

Comment: You could generate polynomials with non-zero roots, and consider them the characteristic polynomial of a matrix.

Comment: Hooked, do you insist that the inverse also have integer entries? If so, you are talking about GL$(N,{\bf Z})$ (maybe better to call it SL$(N,{\bf Z})$). If not, not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very structured matrices, where you know the determinant in advance, use [Vandermonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrices.
One can also disguise them a little.

If you want a **random** component, make the entries on the main diagonal *odd*, and the all the remaining entries in *some* row **or** *some* column even, with the rest of the entries arbitrary.  Then the determinant will be odd, and in particular non-zero.

There are many variants of this idea. For example, choose entries down the main diagonal not divisible by $3$, and the remaining entries in some row or some column divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

a. The answer given by Andre Nicolas is wrong, even for 3x3 matrices. The matrix

1 2 2

a 1 1

b 1 1

has a determinant of 0 no matter what values a and b have.

...

b. I am working on writing a "cookbook" for random generation of matrices with certain properties. For the problem posted by Hooked, I generate:

1. a lower triangular matrix L whose diagonal entries are in {+1,-1} (bonus: if the number of nonzero entries is small, then there aren't that many row operations to perform),
2. an upper triangular matrix U whose diagonal entries are in {+1,-1}, and
3. a random permutation matrix P.

Then A = PLU is a suitable matrix for finding the inverse by hand. Also, the determinants of P, L, and U are +1 or -1, so A has determinant +1 or -1, which means its inverse has integral entries.

Comment: Andre's answer can be partly salvaged by making the  diagonal entries odd (or more generally non-divisible by some prime $p$), all the above-diagonal entries even (or divisible by $p$), and the below-diagonal entries arbitrary integers.  Or interchange "above" and "below".  And again you can pre- or post-multiply by any invertible matrix, in particular permutations.