# Matrices with elements that are a distinct set of prime numbers: always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers

Inspired by a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180882/functions-that-generate-easy-matrices-of-full-rank), given a square non-symmetric matrix whose elements are all prime but distinct from each other, does this guarantee that the matrix is invertible? It's easy to see $N=2$ this holds, a counter-example would imply that there must be four distinct primes such that $p_1 p_2 = p_3 p_4$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. To find a $3 \times 3$ counterexample it suffices to write down three $3$-term prime arithmetic progressions with the same common difference $d$. By inspection $\bmod 2,3$ the smallest possible such difference is $d = 6$, which gives
$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 5 & 11 & 17 \\
 7 & 13 & 19 \\
 31 & 37 & 43 \end{array} \right].$$

Comment: I suppose it is not even necessary for the common differences to be the same, but the next possible common difference is $d = 12$ which I think would lead to a bigger example.

Answer (score 3):

A $4 \times 4$ counterexample is
$$\pmatrix{43 & 17 & 53 & 19 \cr
11 & 71 & 3 & 89 \cr
79 & 47 & 29 & 37 \cr
31 & 7 & 61 & 13 \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for the 4x4 counterexample Robert. Was there any special construction that you used to find it like Qiaochu?

Comment: Nothing so clever.  Actually I did a random search among permutations of the primes $< 100$ taken $16$ at a time.