# Reference request: arranging distinct numbers into a full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I thought of the following problem:

> Let $n\ge 2$.  Suppose you have $n^2$ distinct numbers in some field. 
>   Is it necessarily possible to arrange the numbers into an $n\times n$
>   matrix of full rank (ie, nonsingular or invertible)?

(I am able to solve the problem, for example using the [combinatorial nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Combinatorial_Nullstellensatz).)

I was wondering whether this problem was previous stated elsewhere, perhaps even on this site?

My original motivation for the problem was in fact quite similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180891/19328), but I was rearranging the primes.

Comment: Do you have an answer for the field of Reals?

Comment: @dmtri: It's possible, for all fields.